# Is this a good idea? Authenticate a user in ASP.NET by setting a session variable

Tags: asp.net

To authenticate a user in ASP.NET, I have seen code like this

```
if (loginManager.Authenticate(username, password))
{
    Session["Authenticated"] = 1;
}
```

and in the subsequent request, just check whether the value of `Session["Authenticated"]` is 1  to determine if the current user is authenticated.

This is very simple. My question is: how is this different than ASP.NET Forms Authentication? - Creating an authenticate cookie using FormsAuthentication class and determine whether a user is authenticated based on `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` field ?

Comment: you can find the answer in this SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770848/implementing-security-with-session-variables-how-it-is-insecure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use forms authentication because of few reasons:

1. Forms authentication has been developed by microsoft in many years. Its tested its safe. Your method has never been tested, so neither you nor I can be sure if its safe or not but forms authentication is trusted by all.
2. People struggle a lot with Sessions expiring before time.
3. With many simultaneous users accessing your website, using a session will lead to memory issues.
4. Using forms authentication is cleaner and more elegant.
5. Why not use a approach which many developers use, if tomorrow someone joins your team and helps in your project, he may get your logic wrong and may compromise security.

Answer (score 1):

If the session cookie and the session expiration are synchronized - there will probably have no difference. But this is not always the case. Just one example - you store the Session in the default for ASP.NET - InProc. But for some reason the SessionState process is restarted, killed, dies, whatever - all sessions are gone. Then an user comes to the site - he has a valid Auth cookie and is authenticated. But the session cannot be retrieved, so is re-created as a new(Session.IsNewSession = true). So the user will be authenticated according to FormsAuthentication, but will not have Session["Authenticated"] = 1...

I've found this article very useful on the matter: http://www.abstraction.net/ViewArticle.aspx?articleID=74

> **Do you have a dependency between the user's authentication token and
> his session?**
>
> Ideally, the answer should be no. You should not rely on
> the session data being available for security-related issues for many
> reasons, among others being the separation of concerns. One token
> deals with user access rights, the other with storing user data across
> requests. However, in many cases developers choose to store the user's
> access rights in the session, most often in sites that allow both
> anonymous and authenticated access, with authenticated users having
> more functions / pages available to them then the anonymous ones. **So
> instead of storing an access rights token in the user's authentication
> cookie, developers choose to store the user's access rights in the
> user's session (sometimes because of what is perceived to be a
> security issue – however, this is a generally a false concern, as the
> user's authentication token can be encrypted very strongly an very
> easily through the protection attribute of the forms element in
> web.config). But this assumes that the session does not expire before
> the authentication – otherwise you would be left with an authenticated
> user for which you actually don't know the access rights, as those
> were stored in the session that is now gone**. When faced with this
> dependency, many developers think it will suffice to set the session
> timeout to a higher value than the authentication timeout, and set the
> slidingExpiration to true for the forms authentication. The thinking
> is that in this setup the user authentication will expire first,
> causing the ASP.Net to automatically handle this and redirect the user
> to the login page (as set in the web.config). If the session is still
> around, it will be renewed, if not, a new one will be created and then
> the user's access rights will be set as per his login.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication using session is neither an standard nor a good practice, since sessions are identified using a `SessionID` which is set through FormsAuthentication class. This class takes care of maintaining session binding of a user with server, either by using cookies or if the cookies are disabled it user URL rewriting to maintain `SessionID`. While the session may get lost or compromised, the `SessionID` mechanism is protected by encryption and checking on every request. There are many other reasons to pro this argument. So in short I would recommend to use the standard way.